# Elements only loads after using inspect element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am using the code below to hide/show divs when a link is clicked. The code seems to be working, as it shows one div and hides the others, but the elements inside the divs only show after I click Inspect Element, this is a very strange bug, any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="showinstagram" name="electronics"> Show Me </a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="showinstagram" name="antiques"> Show Me </a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="showinstagram" name="jewelry"> Show Me </a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="showinstagram" name="random"> Show Me </a>

<div style="display:none" class="instagram" id="electronics">
[instashow source="@username" gutter="4" drag_control="false" free_mode="true" scrollbar="false" speed="0" easing="linear" auto_hover_pause="false" popup_deep_linking="true" popup_info="username instagramLink likesCounter commentsCounter description" analytics="false"]
</div>
<div style="display:none" class="instagram" id="antiques">
[instashow source="@username" gutter="4" drag_control="false" free_mode="true" scrollbar="false" speed="0" easing="linear" auto_hover_pause="false" popup_deep_linking="true" popup_info="username instagramLink likesCounter commentsCounter description" analytics="false"]
</div>
<div style="display:none" class="instagram" id="jewelry">
[instashow source="@username" gutter="4" drag_control="false" free_mode="true" scrollbar="false" speed="0" easing="linear" auto_hover_pause="false" popup_deep_linking="true" popup_info="username instagramLink likesCounter commentsCounter description" analytics="false"]
</div>
<div style="display:none" class="instagram" id="random">
[instashow source="@username" gutter="4" drag_control="false" free_mode="true" scrollbar="false" speed="0" easing="linear" auto_hover_pause="false" popup_deep_linking="true" popup_info="username instagramLink likesCounter commentsCounter description" analytics="false"]
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('a').click(function () {
            var divname= this.name;
            $("#"+divname).show().siblings().hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT***: I also noticed that the content in the div also loads if I resize the screen.

Comment: The code seems ok, but what's the actual content of the divs with class `instagram`? Do they have an iframe or some embedded content?

Comment: It's a shortcode that loads photos from instgram

Comment: Can you paste here the code inside of divs with class `instagram`? Just trying to figure out how you display the content from instagram...

Comment: Are you using a wordpress plugin?

Comment: Cleary shoudn't work. [instagram isn't HTML tag and browser display it like text. To do this work you need to use js plugin. Do you have any plugin for this purpose?

Comment: @andreivictor Yes, and the content from instagram shows, but only after I use inspect element or resize the screen.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the fact that the instgram content is set to width: auto; as if i change that it shows. Problem is, I need the content to be responsive, any way I can have both?

Comment: you know you could just use $(this) instead of getting its id ... And don't you need to use siblings().each(function () { $(this).hide()  }) to make sure all its siblings get hidden?